# Remove duplicate rows based on columns range in CSV using Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, duplicates

Using PowerShell, I want to remove duplicate rows based on column range in csv file.

**CSV Content**

```
"SampleID","C2","C3","C4"
"11","C2V1","C3V1","C4V1"
"12","C2V2","C3V2","C4V2"
"13","C2V2","C3V2","C4V2"
"14","C2V3","C3V3","C4V3"
"15","C2V1","C3V1","C4V1"
```

values of C2,C3,C4 columns against SampleID (12 & 13) and (11 & 15) are same. so I want to remove duplicated rows and expect content as below.

**Expected Content**

```
"SampleID","C2","C3","C4"
"11","C2V1","C3V1","C4V1"
"12","C2V2","C3V2","C4V2"
"14","C2V3","C3V3","C4V3"
```

Comment: It would be great if I can display duplication count

Comment: You should post your code and any errors. SO is not intended as a code wrtiing service.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
$csv = @'
"SampleID","C2","C3","C4"
"11","C2V1","C3V1","C4V1"
"12","C2V2","C3V2","C4V2"
"13","C2V2","C3V2","C4V2"
"14","C2V3","C3V3","C4V3"
"15","C2V1","C3V1","C4V1"
'@ | convertfrom-csv
$duplicates = 0
$csv | group-object c2,c3,c4 | foreach-object {
    if ($_.count -gt 1) { $duplicates += $_.count - 1 }
    $_.Group[0]
}
```

Just output `$duplicates` for the duplicate row count.